# Why need worklight adapter instead direct ajax?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I just curious, why we need worklight adapter to communicate with the database? Why not can't using direct ajax? Last time I'm using direct ajax it's not working at all. After I switch to worklight adapter it's running like charm? No problem at all. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide any specific details about your scenario, like Where is that backend system located, if there is any security involved, what is the topology, etc... so why it's not working with AJAX is impossible to answer.

As for why use Worklight adapters, read:

1. http://javatechig.com/cross-platform/ibm-worklight/how-to-create-a-http-adapter-in-ibm-worlight
2. Adapters provide templated (adapter types) connectivity settings to various backend systems - HTTP, SOAP, SQL, JMS and so on
3. Adapters provide a means to auto-generate an adapter for WSDL and sap web services
4. Adapters can also be pure Java JAX-RS web apps, allow far greater flexibility and functionality (in MFP 7.0)
5. You must use Worklight adapters if you intend on using the unified push notifications support
6. Adapters must be used if you intend to utilize any of the Worklight security features (adapter-based, custom login module, device provisioning, custom provisioning and so on)
7. and so on